# What is covered by save(:validate => false)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, counter-cache

I just implemented a number of custom `counter_cache`s using code like this:

```
def after_save
    self.update_counter_cache
end
def after_destroy
    self.update_counter_cache
end
def update_counter_cache
    self.company.new_matchings_count = Matching.where(:read => false).count
    self.company.save
end
```

My question is this - what does the command `Model.save(:validate => false)` actually prevent beyond things like `validates_with` or `before_validation`?

Will my custom counter_caches be affected if I keep my existing saves without validation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you pass in the :validate=>false, it skips the valid? command. Everything else functions the same.

You can check the code out here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations.html

```
def save(options={})
  perform_validations(options) ? super : false
end

...

if perform_validation
  valid?(options.is_a?(Hash) ? options[:context] : nil)
else
  true
end
```

Comment: how do you pass in :validate => false?  I tried <%= form_for(@blob) :validate => false do |f| %> and it broke everything. I'm a bit of a newbie...

Comment: @Michael that's in the update/create method of your controller... `@model.save(:validate=>false)`

Answer (score 4):

Testing on Rails 4.2.6 shows that `.save(:validate=>false)` will actually skip `before_validations` and `after_validation` callbacks.