# Skip password validation with a specific method in the user model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In my `user` model i have validation of `password` and an `instance method` like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :email ......
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }

  def my_method
    # .....
    # save!
  end
end
```

As you can see inside this method i have a call to the `save!` method which save the user after altering some fields, so i want to skip the **validation of password but not other validations** only when i call `my_method` *on a user instance* , how i can do this please ? thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find the solution if someone is interesting, i simply add `attr_accessor :skip_password_validation` to my model, then i add a condition to my password validation `validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }, unless: :skip_password_validation`, and when i call `my_method` in the controller with an instance of user model, i set this attribute above with **true**. it's all , here what the user model will look like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :email ......
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }, unless: :skip_password_validation
  attr_accessor :skip_password_validation

  def my_method
    # .....
    # save!
  end
end
```

In the controller **before** i call **user.my_method** i just add the line : `user.skip_password_validation = true`.

I hope this help you :)

Answer (score -3):

You can do it with 2 methods.

```
model.save(:validate => false)
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5356100/what-is-covered-by-savevalidate-false) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7572652/rails-3-skip-validations-and-callbacks)

OR

Skipping the Callback

```
skip_callback :validate, :before, :check_membership, :if => lambda { self.age > 18 }
```

[API Doc](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Callbacks/ClassMethods/skip_callback)

Comment: :validate => false will skip all other validations, i want just skip password validation

Comment: Oh right. Then you might want to take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542819/in-rails-3-how-can-i-skip-validation-of-the-password-field-when-im-not-attempt)