# Does the parameter "case_insensitive_keys" downcase the keys during validate in recent devise version, and if not which version fixed this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Using devise 4.3.0, the comments in Devise.setup are these:

```
  # Configure which authentication keys should be case-insensitive.
  # These keys will be downcased upon creating or modifying a user and when used
  # to authenticate or find a user. Default is :email.
  config.case_insensitive_keys = [:email]
```

We noticed that the downcasing (lowercasing) occurs during the `validate` of the model.
It was unexpected to have such a data-altering side-effect in a `validate` (and it causes mixed-cased emails to be saved *as-is* to the database in some cases).
This means that downcasing is **not** applied if validation is skipped, e.g.

- `user.save!` <-- the email is downcased
- `user.save(validate: false)` <-- the email is **not** downcased
- `user.update_attribute(:email, "UPPERCASE@test.com")` <-- the email is **not** downcased (because update_attribute [skips validation](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_attribute))

I searched https://github.com/heartcombo/devise for `case_insensitive_keys` to see if the fact that downcasing is applied on `validate` was documented, and if that was still the case in recent versions, and didn't find anything yet.

Does the parameter "case_insensitive_keys" downcase the keys during `validate` in recent devise version, and if not which version fixed this, and at which stage is the downcase done now (and are there still contexts in which devise's downcasing of the keys would not be applied inside Rails)?

Comment: It is in the before valdiation callback: https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/main/lib/devise/models/authenticatable.rb#L71 and https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/main/lib/devise/models/authenticatable.rb#L210 and https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/main/lib/devise/models/authenticatable.rb#L218 Accordingly `save(validate: false)` and `update_attribute` *should* still run callbacks and thus should work appropriately but I have not run through that code at this time.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the source code of `devise/lib/devise/models/authenticatable.rb` --> `before_validation :downcase_keys`.  I can confirm that the code is the same in my version of devise.  The callbacks are run,  but only those that apply.  Since the validation is not run, the `before_validation` callback will never run.  I think this confirms the problem and that it is still a problem to this day, unless there are some other considerations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @engineersmnky's comment, at the time of writing, devise downcases the keys during a `before_validation`.  It has done so since 2011 (it *was* done `before_save` *before* the fix for [this](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/issues/1005) issue).

`before_validation` is not run when validation is skipped, as others have pointed out (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22202651/7037546) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41690696/7037546)), which can result in devise allowing duplicate keys, such as emails, in the database (e.g. `User@test.com` and `user@test.com`), even though the configuration has `config.case_insensitive_keys = [:email]`.

Skipping validation may occur in more circumstances than the two listed in the question.  [This](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fapidock.com%20%22Validation%20is%20skipped%22%20OR%20%22Validations%20are%20skipped%22%20OR%20%22skip_validation%22%20OR%20%22skip%20validation%22) Google search can provide a starting point to find out which type of code can result in skipping the validation.